# How can I apply clipping to mark_text() in altair?

Tags: python, altair

I have my plot clipped so it only shows certain ranges on the y axis. I added text to it using this code:

`text2 = plot2.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy= -8, size = 15).encode(text = alt.Text('Accuracy', format = ',.2f'))`

But this added annotation appears outside of the plot. So I need to get rid of it.

In the plot, I'm using sth like this:`clip = True` in `mark_line()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `clip=True` for the text mark explicitly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 3], 'y': [1, 4], 'text': ['a', 'b']})

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(clip=True).encode(
    x=alt.X('x', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 2])),
    y='y'
)
chart + chart.mark_text().encode(text='text')
```

[image]

```
chart + chart.mark_text(clip=True).encode(text='text')
```

[image]